# Recurrent schwannoma implications?

Tags: nerves, tumors, frequency

In the early 1990's, I had a mass develop along the ulnar nerve where it passes close to the skin at the elbow (the "funny bone" location). It was painful upon impact and palpation, and when it was removed it was diagnosed as a [Schwannoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwannoma).

Recently I have notice a small, but slowly growing nearly BB pellet sized lump that exhibits many of the same characteristics developing in the pad of the ring finger on the same limb (L arm).

Is there a condition where a body is predisposed to developing Schwannoma's and what are the implications if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Neurofibromatosis](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/neurofibromatosis/basics/symptoms/con-20027728) comes in three forms, one of which is called "Schwannomatosis". It usually develops in the patient's 20s or 30s and is characterized by people developing schwannomas.

The most common symptom is pain. A study I could find: [Clinical Features of Schwannomatosis: A Retrospective Analysis of 87 Patients](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3481897/) recommends

> a proactive surveillance plan to identify tumors by magnetic resonance imaging scan in order to optimize surgical treatment and to treat associated pain, anxiety, and depression

However, for perspective:

> Patients with schwannomatosis represent **2.4 to 5%** of all patients requiring schwannoma resection

[Diagnostic criteria for Schwannomatosis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15955931)

So it's not likely. Just one condition that presents with a predisposition for schwannomas.